# Is there a way to switch the '&' in a search query string to '+' or extend the query using multiple text boxes?

Tags: javascript, search, query-string

Example using Craigslist:

```
<form action="/search/sss" id="searchform" method="get">
  <input id="query" name="query" value="car"> 
<select id="catAbb" name="catAbb">
 <option value="sss">all for sale / wanted                  
</select>
  <input type="radio" name="srchType" value="T">
  <input type="radio" name="srchType" value="A" checked="checked">
  <input name="minAsk" class="min" value="$1000">
  <input name="maxAsk" class="max" value="$5000">&nbsp;</td>
  <input type="checkbox" name="hasPic" value="1">
  <input type="submit" value="Search">      
</form>
```

Results in this search string:

```
newyork.craigslist.org/search/sss?query=car&srchType=A&minAsk=$1000&maxAsk=$5000
```

Any way to make the ampersands '&' switch to a '+' so the url will look like this instead:

```
newyork.craigslist.org/search/sss?query=car+srchType=A+minAsk=$1000+maxAsk=$5000
```

The best example is Google's Advanced Search:

```
google.com/search?q=car+"new+car"+honda+OR+toyota+OR+vw+-old+site:autotrader.com+$1000..$5000
```

In other words, any way to manipulate a search form like Google does, to extend the query using multiple input boxes without an ampersand separating each input?

Hope i'm making sense

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  What do you hope to achieve, in other words?

Comment: I should of left out the Craigslist example. Refer to Google Advanced Search. As you type, your info shows up in box in real-time, even though the input boxes have names, i.e. 'as_q', 'as_qdr', etc..they are just an extension of the query 'q'

Comment: edited my answer as a response, that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

in javascript:

var string = "newyork.craigslist.org/search/sss?query=car&srchType=A&minAsk=$1000&maxAsk=$5000"

var newstring = string.replace('&', '+');

//newstring = "newyork.craigslist.org/search/sss?query=car+srchType=A+minAsk=$1000+maxAsk=+5000"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're getting at, but sure - regular expressions can be used to swap out characters. In javascript it would be something like this:

```
myUrl.replace(/\&/g,'+')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have

```
someurl?foo=1&bar=2
```

in your server environment you get a array with

```
foo => 1
bar => 2
```

What google does with

```
googleurl?q=1+2+3
```

if getting one var named q

```
q => 1+2+3
```

And they parse it themselves. There are several other options like [mod rewrite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine), that in my opinion give you much cleaner urls.

But anyway this has to be generated per your javascript, since the browser form default behavior will not work that way.

As a response to your late comment, in jQuery this would look something like

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var query = '';
    $(this).find('inpup, textarea, select').each(function() {
        query += '+'+$(this).val();
    });
    query = escape(query.substr(1));

    //debug
    alert(query);
});
```

Comment: I botched my last question. Tried to be more clear here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923410/how-to-manipulate-the-url-when-a-search-form-is-submitted